# Mapping a free monad DSL into an external one

Tags: haskell, f#, ocaml, dsl

(added Haskell and OCaml tag, as this may be something more common in those worlds)

I've taken a simple API (searchCriteria and runReport) and followed the free monad recipe and created a DSL for it.

e.g.

(for Haskellers think "do" notation)

```
let program = dsl {
        let! searchCriteria = search { channel = Some "Foo" }
        do! runReport ("MyReport",searchCriteria)
    }
```

and written the corresponding interpreter, so I can write "programs" and then "interpret" them separately.

and that works quite nicely....follow the recipe...out pops a DSL.

Really I want to serialise this to JSON or something similar, so I need to define a formal syntax that captures this monadic syntax....so something like?

```
type VarName = string
type ChannelName = string
type Report = string

type MExpression =
    | SearchDay of ChannelName
    | RunReport of Report * Expression
and Expression = 
    | ValueOf of VarName
type ProgramLine = 
    | Let of VarName * MExpression
    | Do of MExpression
```

where an MExpression is an expression in the monad, and ValueOf is just the evaluation of the variable thats been assigned.

then I can express my program like this

```
type ExternalDSL = ProgramLine list

let foo : ExternalDSL = 
    [ Let ("days", SearchDay "Foo")
      Do (RunReport ("MyReport",ValueOf "days")) ]
```

and write some transformation from the above into my free monad version (though it becomes a free monad over effectively a map of variables to their values as objects...which you have to cast out), and then execute it.

My grammar (MExpression etc) feels contrived, is there an "off the shelf" recipe for this? obviously for each method on the API, I'd add a new value to DExpression.

for example, maybe I can add the ability to nest these "programs" by adding something like

```
    | Nest of (ProgramLine list * VarName)
```

where the VarName is the name of the variable to return (that seems wrong!)

so I feel this encoding of the grammar isnt correct, someone must have done this before? in some standard CS textbook?

Comment: This sounds cool, but I'm not sure exactly what your question is. If you're just wondering if there's some sort of standard DSL for representing programs/statements/expressions in F#, I think the answer is probably no.

Comment: no...its more a CS question....is there a standard way to take a free monad encoding of an API (see https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/08/07/f-free-monad-recipe/), to then serialise to a something like JSON....it maybe better on a Haskell group

Comment: actually @brainberns...yes...though it obviously doesnt need to be F#.